# Epsilon Delta Proof help

Tags: functions, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Prove the stated limit is correct...

$$\lim_{x → -2}\frac{1}{(x + 1)} =  -1 $$

So far I have managed to reduce it to

$$|\frac{1}{(x + 1)}||x+2| < ε \text{ if } 0<|x+2|<δ$$

and then I would usually set delta less or equal to one and go from there,

$$|x+2|<1$$

and try rearrange it to
$$  \text{ stuff } < \frac{1}{(x + 1)}< \text{ stuff }$$

Im not really sure how to do this part. I've only been learning epsilon-delta from this morning so I would appreciate a thorough explanation.

Comment: You have a sign error.  It should be $0<|x+2|<\delta.$  It will be a lot easier once you fix this.

Comment: Oh whoops. I will edit accordingly. My on paper working however did not have this mistake so I still have the same issue.

Comment: You might want to look at all of the posted answers. The ones posted fastest are always the best ones.

Comment: Yeah true, you mean 'aren't' always though I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to conclude that $$\left| \dfrac 1 {x+1} \right| \left| x+2 \right|<\varepsilon.$$ So you need to figure out what to do with $\left| \dfrac 1 {x+1} \right|.$ The fact that $x$ is between $-2\pm\delta$ enables us to say something about $\left| \dfrac 1 {x+1} \right|$ provided we know something about $\delta.$ If $\delta$ is small the two numbers $-2\pm\delta$ are negative, and we have
\begin{align}
& -2-\delta < x < -2+\delta \\[10pt]
& -1-\delta < x+1 < -1 + \delta \\[10pt]
& \frac 1 {-1-\delta} > \frac 1 {x+1} > \frac 1 {-1+\delta} \\[10pt]
& \frac 1 {1+\delta} < \left| \frac 1 {x+1}\right| < \frac 1 {1-\delta} \\
& \quad \text{Here we relied on the fact that all three numbers were negative,} \\
& \quad \text{so taking absolute values amounts to multiplication by }-1. \\[10pt]
\text{So } & \left| \frac 1 {x+1} \right| \le 2 \text{ if } \delta\le \frac 1 2. \\[10pt]
\text{And then } & \left| \frac 1 {x+1} \right| |x+2| < 2\delta \text{ if } |x+2|<\delta. \\[10pt]
\text{We want } & \left| \frac 1 {x+1} \right| |x+2| < \varepsilon. \\[12pt]
\text{So let } & \delta = \begin{cases} 1/2, \\ \varepsilon/2, \end{cases} \text{ whichever is less.}
& 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. My textbook states that the answer is δ = min(1, ε/(1+ε)). Is it possible this is a mistake?

Comment: @copa : There's more than one way to choose $\delta,$ since all you need is to choose a value that's small enough.

Comment: Ah yes of course. The chapter even has a subsection, 'The value of \text{ δ } is not unique'!

Answer (score 2):

As you already took $\delta<1$,
$|x+2|<1 \implies -1<x+2<1 \implies -2<x+1<0\implies -\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{x+1}<\infty.$

Take $\delta<\frac{1}{2}$ it will solve this problem.

Comment: Oh, you didn't realise you could do that.

Comment: it is always possible to make delta less than 1

Comment: I meant the last bit where you talk the reciprocal of everything. Also, I edited the post as I made a formatting error, namely, all 'x-2' should be 'x+2'

Comment: yes. sorry! I will correct it. Thank you.